# Ruby on Rails - Small activerecord and view rendering time yet big response time

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.2

I have a Ruby on Rails application that is working fine for most of the API requests but for some API requests it just hangs. ActiveRecord queries are made in small time and also view is rendered in small time as well but yet response time is very big.

Rails version is 4.2.5 and Ruby version is 2.2.0, Database that I am using is Postgresql. Below I am attaching my Gemfile and also production log and also the code for which this is happening.

Production.log

```
I, [2019-09-07T09:23:45.748270 #22745]  INFO -- : Started GET "/api/v3/restaurants/1/accepted_orders?skip_search=1" for
    165.228.89.233 at 2019-09-07 09:23:45 +0000 
I, [2019-09-07T09:23:45.753331 #22745]  INFO -- : Processing by Api::V3::Staff::OrdersController#accepted_index as JSON 
I, [2019-09-07T09:23:45.753387 #22745]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"skip_search"=>"1", "id"=>"1"} 
D, [2019-09-07T09:23:45.756807 #22745] DEBUG -- :   User Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]] 
D, [2019-09-07T09:23:45.761643 #22745] DEBUG -- :   User Load (3.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."uid" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["uid", "example@gmail.com"]] 
D, [2019-09-07T09:23:45.765724 #22745] DEBUG -- :   Eula Load (3.1ms)  SELECT  "eulas".* FROM "eulas" WHERE "eulas"."is_latest" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["is_latest", "t"]] 
D, [2019-09-07T09:23:45.768793 #22745] DEBUG -- :   Privacy Load (2.7ms)  SELECT  "privacies".* FROM "privacies" WHERE "privacies"."is_latest" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["is_latest", "t"]] 
D, [2019-09-07T09:23:45.772602#22745] DEBUG -- :   Restaurant Load (3.0ms)  SELECT  "restaurants".* FROM "restaurants" WHERE "restaurants"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]] 
D, [2019-09-07T09:23:46.293350 #22745] DEBUG -- :   Order Load (519.6ms)  SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."restaurant_id" IN (1) 
D, [2019-09-07T10:44:50.564263 #22745] DEBUG -- :    (19.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."status" = $1 AND "orders"."restaurant_id" = 1 AND ( DATE(orders.created_at) >= '2019-09-07 09:45:50 UTC')  [["status", 1]] 
D, [2019-09-07T10:44:50.577108 #22745] DEBUG -- :    (11.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."status" = $1 AND "orders"."restaurant_id" = 1 AND ( DATE(orders.created_at) >= '2019-09-07 09:45:50 UTC')  [["status", 0]] 
D, [2019-09-07T10:44:50.580691 #22745] DEBUG -- :   User Exists (1.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'example@gmail.com' AND "users"."id" != 6) LIMIT 1 
D, [2019-09-07T10:44:50.582116 #22745] DEBUG -- :   User Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."username" = 'Staff 1' AND "users"."id" != 6) LIMIT 1 
D, [2019-09-07T10:44:50.584594#22745] DEBUG -- :   User Exists (1.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."phone_number" = '+777777777' AND "users"."id" != 6) LIMIT 1 
I, [2019-09-07T10:44:50.586265 #22745] INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 4864833ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord:
        570.2ms)
```

Part of code having the error

```
api :GET, '/v3/restaurants/:id/accepted_orders', 'Returns all accepted orders of a restaurant (for staff and owners)'
param :id, String, desc: 'id of the restaurant', required: true
def accepted_index
  query = " DATE(orders.created_at) >= '#{59.minutes.ago}'" if current_user.staff?
  accepted = Order.where(status: Order.statuses[:accepted], restaurant: @restaurant).where(query)
  pending = Order.where(status: Order.statuses[:pending], restaurant: @restaurant).where(query)
  render json: {accepted_count: accepted.count, pending_count: pending.count}
end
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.0'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'annotate'

gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
gem 'paper_trail', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'dotenv-rails'
# MailChimp integration
gem 'gibbon'
gem 'google_directions'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'stripe', :git => 'https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby'
# The push notification service.
gem 'rpush', github: 'rpush/rpush'
gem 'prawn-rails'
gem 'prawn-table'
gem 'active_admin_datetimepicker'
gem 'phony_rails'
gem 'closure_tree'
gem 'whenever', require: false
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end
group :development do
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'letter_opener'
end
gem 'apipie-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem 'high_voltage'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'devise_token_auth'
gem 'sidekiq', '~> 4.0', '>= 4.0.1'
# gem 'ckeditor', '~> 4.1', '>= 4.1.5'
gem 'socket.io-client-simple'
gem 'houston'
gem 'fancybox-rails', '~> 0.3.0'
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.6'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 0.10.0'
gem 'fog', '~> 1.36'
gem 'chosen-rails'
gem 'twilio-ruby', '~> 4.11.1'
group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'rails_layout'
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.1.0'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', '~> 1.1.2'
  gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1.1'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm', github: "capistrano/rvm"
  gem 'capistrano-sidekiq'
  gem 'rest-client'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'fakeredis'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 3.0'
  gem 'shoulda-callback-matchers', '~> 1.1.1'
  gem 'redis-namespace'
end
group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end
gem 'sinatra', :require => nil
```

On production server I am using nginx and Passenger.

Thanks

Comment: Don't have enough information to debug, but I'd suspect some kind of resource lock.

Comment: What more info do you need, tell me and I will try to get it.

Comment: Looking at the existing log, there is a 1 hour gap between loading all orders and counting orders. I'd focus my search on the code path between those 2. Also look into monitoring and logging slow Postgres queries.